# Mouse click movement

Tags: unity, 3d, mathematics, rotation, movement

I need to make realistic human movement (3D) using mouse click.

1. Get mouse click point using `Raycast`.
2. Smoothly `Slerp` to `LookRotation`.
3. Move `transform.forward`.

Everything works fine, except I have problem with circular movement (close radius).

1. [Example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLL5sP7dnLQ) If **dont** move `transform.forward` while `Slerp` to `LookRotation` or `MoveTowards` instead of `transform.forward` it will be spinning like whirligig on circular movement.
2. [Example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_HrzqSp3h-c) If **do** move `transform.forward` while while `Slerp` to `LookRotation` it will distort trajectory of straight direct movement.

Is there any solution to move circular realistic (not spin like whirligig) and move straight direct when needed (not distort trajectory)?

I need straight movement from first example and circular movement from second.

```
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

            RaycastHit[] hits = Physics.RaycastAll(ray);

            foreach (RaycastHit hit in hits)
            {
                if (hit.transform.tag == "Ground")
                {
                    DestinationPosition = new Vector3(hit.point.x, transform.position.y, hit.point.z);

                    DestinationRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(DestinationPosition - transform.position);

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, DestinationPosition) > 1)
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, DestinationRotation, RotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            transform.position += transform.forward * MovementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

            //transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, DestinationPosition, MovementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            animation.CrossFade("run");
        }
        else
        {
            animation.CrossFade("idle");
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps you should only move forward when you're actually facing the destination? I'd imagine Quaternion.Slerp isn't rotating you all the way to the destination in one frame, and then you are moving foward regardless. Try replacing transform.forward with ( destinationPosition - transform.position ).normalized in the last line. That will move you towards the destination whether or not you're facing it.

Comment: I realize that I can move towards destination whether or not I'm facing it using `Vector3.MoveTowards` (which should be equivalent of (`DestinationPosition - transform.position).normalized`) instead of `transform.towards`, but that make circular movement look unnatural (spinning like whirligig).

Comment: Then why not wait until it's fully rotated before starting to move forward?

Comment: How natural is staying on same spot and rotating? When moving circular we need move using arc trajectory (which is achieved moving and rotating at same time). But when turn around we need keep linear trajectory.

Comment: Well you haven't exactly provided any context into what you're actually moving. All I can gather from your post is it's obviously not a "whirligig".

Comment: You might want to consider that there are quite a few players out there with an intense dislike of click-to-move mechanics in 1st/3rd-person games.  If you do use click-to-move, it might behoove you to allow it to be disabled in favor of WASD (or better still, customizable) keyboard movement.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on the problem. I mean, sure the character rotating over and over in those videos looks silly, but that's because the cursor keeps spinning around them; of course a character will have unnatural looking movement if the player is giving it unnatural movement commands. Perhaps you should show us a video of an existing game doing what you are trying to implement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When facing this problem I found that I wanted the  character to move forward at a velocity roughly proportional to how close they are to facing the target.

When facing away from our target we "turn on the spot" (Red), when facing directly towards it we walk straight towards it (Green), when somewhere in between we will may walk slowly while turning (Blue & Purple).

[image]

How best to implement this, and the values to use for thresholds, will depend on the other systems already in place.

One approach with Unity that would allow for easy fine tuning would be to use an [AnimationCurve](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationCurve.html).

```
public AnimationCurve speedAngleCurve;
public float maxSpeed;

private float getTargetSpeed(Vector3 targetPosition) {
    Vector3 targetDirection = targetPosition - transform.position;
    float offsetAngle = Vector3.Angle(transform.forward, targetDirection);
    float normalizedAngle = offsetAngle / 180.0f;
    return speedAngleCurve.Evaluate(normalizedAngle) * maxSpeed;
}
```

This would allow a developer to rapidly modify behaviour using the Inspector and the [Curve Editor](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/EditingCurves.html).

[image]

Comment: Movement direction would be always `transform.forward`?

Comment: Yeah, this sample is treating `forward` as the facing/movement direction.  It is just a quick example of one method to map the facing/target relationship to a movement speed.  Any real implementation will need fleshing out to consider turning, acceleration, animation, applying movement etc.